# Permission issue while downloading files from website using Python 2.7

Tags: python-2.7, urllib

I am trying to download set of files from a website into my local drive in Windows using Python 2.7 but getting permission denied error:

One of the examples is below:

```
urllib.urlretrieve('http://www.renderx.com/files/demos/examples/Fund.pdf',"c://python")

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#151>", line 1, in <module>
    urllib.urlretrieve('http://www.renderx.com/files/demos/examples/Fund.pdf',"c://python")
  File "C:\Python\Python27\lib\urllib.py", line 94, in urlretrieve
    return _urlopener.retrieve(url, filename, reporthook, data)
  File "C:\Python\Python27\lib\urllib.py", line 244, in retrieve
    tfp = open(filename, 'wb')
IOError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: 'c://python'
```

When I don't specify a path, it downloads files (without any issue) into path where Python is installed C://pyhton//Python27... But I want to download all the files in a specific folder.
Can you please help me in the issue?

Answer (score 1):

If you don't specify a path, python will take the path of the `.py` file you runned.

As the you provided the second argument the folder name(`c://python`) that already exist, it probably tried to replace your python directory(`c://Python`).

You can give the second argument a `filename` for the downloading file(if same file already exist you may get error). ie:

```
urllib.urlretrieve('http://www.renderx.com/files/demos/examples/Fund.pdf',
"c://python//fund.pdf")
```

I assume this will store the file `fund.pdf` in the `python` directory

Comment: if this solution solved your problem, you can mark as solved.  :)  (the green check mark  )